QWT - Why doesn't my legend reflect the symbols for each curve?
I am creating a plot using QWT with QT 5.15.
I've added a legend to the plot, but for some reason while the COLOR of each item in the legend is correct, the symbols are wrong. It's always a square instead of the symbol that curve is using.
Here's an example picture:

How do I make the legend symbols match?
Here's initializing the plot:
  ui->setupUi(this);

  m_qwtp = new QwtPlot(this);
  ui->verticalLayout->insertWidget(0, m_qwtp);
  setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

  // Set the chart's title
  QwtText title("Temperature History");
  title.setFont(QFont("sans", 14, QFont::Bold));
  m_qwtp->setTitle(title);

  // See qwt_axis.h's Position enum for which correspond to which
  // 2 = bottom x axis, 0 = left y axis
  m_qwtp->setAxisTitle(QwtAxis::Position::XBottom, "Time [sec]");
  m_qwtp->setAxisTitle(QwtAxis::Position::YLeft, "Temperature [K]");
  m_qwtp->setAxisScale(QwtAxis::Position::YLeft, 0.9 * tempMinimum,
                       1.1 * tempMaximum, 0.0);

  m_qwtp->insertLegend(new QwtLegend());

And here's the method for adding each plot:
void addPlot(double depth, int plotCount, QVector<double>& QTimes, QVector<double>& QTemps)
{
  // Set the scale of the X axis
  // This is the same for each plot added, but it doesn't matter
  m_qwtp->setAxisScale(QwtAxis::Position::XBottom, QTimes.first(),
                       1.075 * QTimes.last(), 0.0);

  // Create a new curve and set the title
  QwtPlotCurve* curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
  curve->setTitle(QString("Zone at depth: %1 cm").arg(depth));

  // Add the data points
  QPolygonF points;

  for (int i = 0; i < QTimes.size(); i++)
    {
      points << QPointF(QTimes[i], QTemps[i]);
    }

  curve->setSamples(points);

  // Give each curve a unique color
  QColor color(qSin(plotCount * 1.1 + 1.2) * 80 + 80,
               qSin(plotCount * .3) * 80 + 80,
               qSin(plotCount * 0.3 + 1.7) * 80 + 80);

  QPen pen;
  pen.setColor(color);
  pen.setWidth(2);
  pen.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);

  curve->setPen(pen);
  curve->setRenderHint(QwtPlotItem::RenderAntialiased, true);

  // Decide which symbol to use. We use a rotating list of 15 to try to make
  // each one distinct.
  QwtSymbol* symbol;
  if (plotCount % 15 == 0)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::Ellipse, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 1)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::Rect, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 2)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::Diamond, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 3)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::Triangle, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 4)
    {
      symbol = new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::DTriangle, QBrush(color), pen,
                             QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 5)
    {
      symbol = new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::UTriangle, QBrush(color), pen,
                             QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 6)
    {
      symbol = new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::LTriangle, QBrush(color), pen,
                             QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 7)
    {
      symbol = new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::RTriangle, QBrush(color), pen,
                             QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 8)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::Cross, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 9)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::XCross, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 10)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::HLine, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 11)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::VLine, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 12)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::Star1, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 13)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::Star2, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }
  else if (plotCount % 15 == 14)
    {
      symbol =
          new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::Hexagon, QBrush(color), pen, QSize(10, 10));
    }

  curve->setSymbol(symbol);

  curve->attach(m_qwtp);

  m_qwtp->replot();
}

